# Como importar o css no Angular 6?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

Eu percebi que da versão Angular 4.3 para o Angular 6 eles retiraram o arquivo **.angular-cli.json**, por causa disso estou incluindo no arquivo principal do projeto o **index.html**, mas a importação o Font-Awesome não está funcionando, alguém teria uma sugestão?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No angular 6 o arquivo de configuração foi renomeado pra angular.json mas ainda funciona do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Conseguir resolver o problema graças a sua sugestão, pode colocar sua respsta para eu marca como certa. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro realize a instalação do font-awesome pelo npm.

```
npm install font-awesome
```

Depois basta adicionar no seu **angular.json** na area style como abaixo. Coloquei já o bootstrap no exemplo também.

```
 ....
 "styles": [
     "src/styles.css",
     "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
     "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
 ],
.....
```

Note que esse caminho usa a pasta node_module padrão. Caso você utilize de outra forma basta colocar seu caminho e irá funcionar.

Dessa forma o angular irá gerenciar essas importações inclusive otimizando para build.